# How to extract another frequently changed website link and paste in your website

Tags: php, image, hyperlink, explode

I need help guys
There is one website which uploads images daily on the index page and all have a different image link So want to extract that image link for example -

```
<img width="80" src="www.example.com/image/abcdefg.jpg">
```

I want a script which takes the link from the above site and copies the "abcdefg.jpg" word and automatically paste it into my home page so that same pictures show in both the website  every time that site's admin changes the image

Like this -

```
$THATLINK = "abcdefg.jpg";    //how I can get that specific link if everytime its change in that website ?

<?php echo $THATLINK ?>

<img width="80" src="www.MYWEBSITE.com/image/<?php echo $THATLINK ?>">
```

Comment: What have you tried? We can help you with your code, but we will not code it for you.

Comment: Sorry my mistake in writing I don't mean that

I am stuck there so I need HELP

Comment: do you have permission to use this other sites contents

Comment: No i don't have permission that's why i am asking so get that by other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image won't show up until you have fetched that image to your own server . To extract the name you can use curl extension to get the page and then parse it for that specific image tag for that attribute !!

Comment: AnuragD - Sir i don't know much about PHP can you please give me in details ?

Comment: Okay then simply use file_get_contents(the url from which you want to fetch the image) . Next google for a html parser . There are many open source php html parsers available . Use it to get the image link from the page that you fetch . then use the link directly on your page , you don't need to add your domain name before it !!

Comment: Wow...that great thanks a lot AnuragD :)